# Null Cert Chain Exception

Tags: java, ssl, netty

I have a setup with one server talking with several network devices over xmpp. Netty is used as xmpp server. Kind of heart beat server. SSL authentication is first done before the communication starts.

Though the certificate details are proper in the client and server , i am seeing lot of null cert chain exception in the server logs. When i checked about this error , all resources are pointing that client personal certificate missing, which is causing this error.

Its impossible because the devices are factory made and come with certificate by default.

I want to know what could be the reasons for Null Cert Chain exception apart from the client certificate.

Comment: Why do you expect the devices fresh from the factory to contain certificates? As far as I understand it's not complaining that the devices cannot verify the certificate of the servers. The server tells you, that it tried to authenticate the client using a client certificate and the client did not have one of this. The certificates preinstalled are root certificates of certification authorities. The certificates you need for client authentication are actually something different and also contain private keys.